# Volley DiskBasedCache throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-volley, android-lru-cache

I'm using [BitmapLRUCache by Trey Robinson](https://github.com/rdrobinson3/VolleyImageCacheExample/blob/master/CaptechBuzz/src/com/captechconsulting/captechbuzz/model/images/BitmapLruImageCache.java) for image caching in my Android app. It's an implementation of LRU cache for Volley as it doesn't provide any image caching by itself.

Though it does use [DiskBasedCache](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/DiskBasedCache.java) for caching HTTP requests. Now coming to the problem, I get FileNotFoundExceptions repeatedly when DiskBasedCache tries to get or remove cache entries.

Sample log below.

```
 23833                 Volley  D  [47291] DiskBasedCache.remove: Could not delete cache entry for key=http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music1/v4/69/66/0b/69660b50-7771-a43a-919f-26d8b6ae37aa/UMG_cvrart_00602537957941_01_RGB72_1500x1500_14UMGIM31675.400x400-75.jpg, filename=1509125231-2004731303
 23833                 Volley  D  [47291] DiskBasedCache.get: /data/data/com.vibin.billy.debug/cache/volley/6408634861932551223: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.vibin.billy.debug/cache/volley/6408634861932551223: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 23833                 Volley  D  [47291] DiskBasedCache.remove: Could not delete cache entry for key=http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music4/v4/99/f7/ac/99f7ac13-0dd6-8841-96e0-2a1c18041d84/UMG_cvrart_00602537854097_01_RGB72_1800x1800_14UMGIM03851.400x400-75.jpg, filename=6408634861932551223
```

Why is DiskBasedCache handling image caching when I'm initializing the ImageLoader with BitmapLRUcache (see below)?

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this), new BitmapLruCache());
```

Below is the code I'm using for caching.

```
package com.vibin.billy;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

/**
 * Basic LRU Memory cache.
 *
 * @author Trey Robinson
 */
public class BitmapLruCache
        extends LruCache<String, Bitmap>
        implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {

    private static final String TAG = BitmapLruCache.class.getSimpleName();

    public BitmapLruCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }


    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Grab "+url);
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
         //Log.d(TAG, "Put "+url);
         put(url, bitmap);
    }

    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory =
                (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        Log.d(TAG, "cachesize is " + cacheSize);

        Log.d(TAG,cacheSize+" is cache Size");

        return cacheSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your cache code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is DiskBasedCache handling image caching when I'm initializing the
>   ImageLoader with BitmapLRUcache (see below)?

for image caching volley use 2 level cache mechanism, that means one level is in your `RAM` `BitmapLRUcache` and another one is on your Disk `DiskBasedCache`. why? because of reading and writing images from disk takes longer time than just simply reading and writing some `Strings` and gives poor performance. so at the first time when you request `Volley` to download your images `Volley` first looks at the cache level one, if your images are not there `Volley` looks at cache level 2 and if your images are not there `Volley` sends your download request to the server.

> I get FileNotFoundExceptions repeatedly when DiskBasedCache tries to
>   get or remove cache entries.

because your `DiskBasedCache` size is limited(by default is 5MB) and also it is `LRU`, which means if `Volley` wants to store an image on the `DiskBasedCache` and it dose not have any space, it is going to delete some of the old entries that it holds and dose not references recently.(LRU=Least Recently Used) So the remove function is called.

Comment: Yes I guessed the 5MB limit was the culprit. How do I increase it?

Comment: `private static final int DEFAULT_DISK_USAGE_BYTES = 5 * 1024 * 1024;` from the class of `DiskBasedCache`

Comment: So should I extend the class and change the value?

Comment: No, just replace `5` by for example `10`.

Comment: you should change it and you must use volley as a library project.

Comment: Cool, will do that. Thanks for the answer and suggestions!

Comment: Hey, I got around the FileNotFoundExceptions, but Volley still doesn't load all the bitmaps from cache. (It was same previously.)

Current app cache is around 4.71MB. That's less than 5MB. Why would this happen?

Here's a screenshot https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/udbX3-DNFB1kryH8XM7rCmicsUssbGKYSKvh57/Screenshot_2014-10-08-22-12-39.png

Comment: have you increased cache size?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still using Volley as an AAR, with this code.
https://gist.github.com/vibinr/6aac5ceda47c76463d95

Comment: What else do you think would go wrong? Please guide or give a hint

Comment: sorry, I helped you, but I can not now!