# Android Volley error in getInstance(this) when adding ImageLoader

Tags: android, singleton, android-volley

I am following up [image cashing tutorial using Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) on Android developers, I am having problem with requesting an image request and caching it, I guess because of the singelton that I created (copied from the tutorial).

My Eclipse is giving error in the `getInstance(this)` because this is context and I am requesting an image I guess.

```
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(
    url,
    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
            mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
        //  mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
        //  mImageLoader.get(IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mImageView,
        //      R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            }
        },
    0,
    0,
    null,
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //  mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    });
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

This is singleton:

```
package com.example.p;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(
            mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

I am able to get the image and display it in such way , but I need to cache it , so I guess it to add it in a request right ? .. any help ?

```
mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
```

Comment: Java's basics: what `this` means, how use outer class inside anonymous interface implementation

Comment: @Selvin I thought it refers to the context of the activity, as this activity. anyway i still dont understand how to solve my above problem,  I guess you dont know how to use volley right?

Comment: I know how to use volley, but you don't know java... Also what is the point of getting singleton instance when in onResponse you already have the bitmap?

Comment: @Selvin  I am learning java , now I am googling about `this` to update my knowledge about java, and if you know volley can you help me with my question ?

Comment: well  thats what it described in the tutorial , I mentioned in my question without the onResponse its working, so my the singleton work I should remove the instance ? @Selvin

Comment: You should put the logcat (error message) for more information.

Comment: @ChungPham I wasnt able to run the app because I had syntax error , the error as described in the question is here                         mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
 due to instace,  all i want is a way to send this mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
                        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
                        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader); as request and cach it .. can you help me with that ?

Comment: I have just added my answer.

Comment: @Moudiz In the above code you actually add `ImageCache` at `new ImageLoader.ImageCache() { ... }` in `MySingleton` class.

Comment: @hata so no need for a request because the singleton ?

Comment: @Moudiz The instance (**`mImageLoader`**) you get at `mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();` has already been convined with ImageCache in `MySingleton`. There is no need for additional operation for enabling caching.

Comment: @hata ok yes I understand you , but in the android tutorial they said I need to do a [request](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/request.html).. my question is in the imageloader I didnt hadn't to do a request, I was able to get the image without a request . understand me now ?

Comment: @hata btw a stupid question, but how does the cash work ? I assigned  new ImageLoader.ImageCache() in singleton , I opened the app and I saw the image , when I closed the app the image diseapered, shouldnt the image stay because its cached ?

Comment: @Moudiz When you `setImageUrl` on `mNetworkImageView`, the `imageLoader` does `ImageRequest` internally.

Comment: @Moudiz `ImageCache` is **L1 Cache**. That means it resides only during the app is launching. Volley also has internal L2 Cache (`DiskBasedCache`). It's size is 5MB.

Comment: @hata I was doing some google about `DiskBasedCache`but I couldnt find anything helpful tutorial or examples about it especially there was some [performance problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916478/performance-issue-with-volleys-diskbasedcache) , your informations and help is really apreciated

Comment: @Moudiz You should read the source code of Volley if you are interested in `DiskBasedCache`. And such discussions are beyond commenting. If you have further questions, please post new questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86954/discussion-between-moudiz-and-hata).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my working sample code. Hope this help:

MainActivity.java:

```
import ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context mContext = this;   

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

        String mUrl = "http://192.168.0.100/api/getimage";
        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(mUrl, VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader());       
    }

    ...  

}
```

VolleySingleton.java:

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mContext;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 10 * 1024 * 1024); // this for caching
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }   
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">       

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/networkImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />       

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.volleyapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried your example but when I close the app then open it , the image disapear, how then the image should be cached ?

Comment: what if I want to add DiskBasedCache? can you please add it in your example ?

Comment: I think you can find more about caching [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193501/volley-diskbasedcache-throws-filenotfoundexception). Try increase your cache size. Goodluck!

Comment: Hi! I updated my answer. Look at `Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);`, this is for caching

Comment: shoudlnt i add diskcache ? and now I am trying to show the images in arraylist adapter , do you a ready simple example that you can help me with ?

Comment: That's diskcache, you can press Ctrl-B at `newRequestQueue` to view more details (which will be `newRequestQueue(Context context, int maxDiskCacheBytes)`)

Comment: oh nice ill check that thanks a alot , I have another question I was following this [tutoria android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volleyl](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) and it worked good. but I am have problem implementing in his code the diskcache , do u have a simple example with your code to display the imageloader in a listview ?

Comment: ok thanks anyway , tonight Ill post what I have already done in my code , and If you can help me that would be great :d

Comment: Try the above newRequestQueue for your listview example and check if it caches or not.

Answer (score 1):

You´r in the wrong Context .. init a class member

```
private final Context ctx = this;
```

and than use ctx inside onResponse

```
mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(ctx).getImageLoader();
```

Answer (score 1):

One optimization suggestion for the getInstance method is to use double checked locking as it only synchronizes in case the instance is actually null:

```
private volatile static VolleySingleton self;

public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (self == null) {
        //Using double checked locking
        synchronized (VolleySingleton.class) {
            if (self == null) {
                //Using app context prevents leaking of activity context
                self = new VolleySingleton(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

More information on singletons and the different ways of instantiating them can be found [here](https://javarevealed.wordpress.com/tag/initialization-on-demand-holder/).

The volatile keyword ensures, that the field is immediately seen by all threads and is not cached thread-locally. If the getInstance did not require a Context, there are other method explained in the link that would be more suitable than double checked locking.